# FolderPicker instantly closing for no reason

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using that code to pick a folder, and it works perfectly fine.

```cs
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder pickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

But when I'm using it in a specific function I don't know why it suddenly won't work anymore.

So here's exactly what I'm doing from the button click to the FolderPicker popup.

Button click :

```cs
private async void BRechercherPoste_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbCodePoste != null && !tbCodePoste.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        string codePoste = tbCodePoste.Text;

        //recuperation des infos du poste
        await ViewModel.getPosteInformationsAsync(codePoste);
    }
}
```

... then `ViewModel.getPosteInformationsAsync` :

```cs
public async Task getPosteInformationsAsync(string posteNumber)
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    await setupFiles();

    [some code not interferring here]
}
```

... setupFiles :

```cs
public static async Task setupFiles()
{
    //checks for the first time app launch 
    if (!await checkIfPosteFolderPresentAsync())
    {}
        PosteChoiceDialog dialogChoice = new PosteChoiceDialog();
        //showing a dialog with 2 choices
        await dialogChoice.ShowAsync();
    }

    [rest of the code (working)]
}
```

So the dialog shows 2 choices, one that loads default data in the `LocalFolder` and one letting you choose a personal folder to load the data in the `LocalFolder`.

The function that triggers when you choose the 2nd option is that one :

```cs
public static async Task loadCustomPosteInformation()
{
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    //---Here the folder picker open and closes instantly for no reason---//
    StorageFolder pickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//

    //Because it's not working the rest of the function crashes
    if (pickedFolder == null)
    {
        await loadDefaultPosteInformation();
    }
    else
    {
        var files = await pickedFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        StorageFolder postes = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Postes");

        foreach (StorageFile f in files)
        {
            await f.CopyAsync(postes);
        }
    }
}
```

So I detailed everything I could because I searched for hours why it was crashing and I really don't understand why the `FolderPicker` keeps instantly closing only in that specific function.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with the `PickSingleFolderAsync()` call not being in the UI thread, although if that were the case I don't know why it would open (and close) in the first place.

Still, why don't you try calling `StorageFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync()` from the UI thread:

```
StorageFolder pickedFolder;
var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<StorageFolder>();
var folderDialogTask = completionSource.Task;
Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
async () =>
{
      var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
      completionSource.SetResult(folder);
});`
pickedFolder = await folderDialogTask;
```

Comment: Tried it, still opening for 0,2 sec and instantly closing without any error.

Comment: have you tried adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync() so that it runs synchronously? It could be the asynchronous code that is causing your folder picker to close instantly because it is getting disposed or out of scope.